# Program/script to 'walk' through svn revision history

Tags: linux, bash, vim, svn, vimdiff

Looking for a program, or script, I can use to easily 'walk' through an SVN revision history for a specific file. Anyone know if this exists? Can I achieve this with the command line client for svn?

What I'd like to be able to do:

- request diff for file between revision x and x-1 (I use a script that show me the diff in vimdiff, similar to this:http://tierseven.net/wiki/index.php?title=Svndiff.sh )
- while staying inside vimdiff, call 'next' or 'prev' command, and show me diff between x and x-2, or between x-1 and x-2

I'd rustle something up in bash/sed/awk, but I'd rather use something that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

`svn log -q -v filename` and processing output for revlist

`svn diff -c M filename` for changes in filename in revision M

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log FILENAME_GOES_HERE --limit 20 | grep -P 'r\d+ \|' | sed s/^r// | sed s/\ .*// | xargs -L 1 svn diff DancerAdmin/templates/Common/inputs/ss-dropdown.html -c | less
```

There's probably a better way to do it with awk instead of sed, or even a better way to do it with sed, but this works.

Outputs the last 20 versions of this file to `less`. From there, you can search for Index: (`/Index:[Enter]`) and then use `n`/`N` to "page" up and down through the revision history.

Just to explain what's going on here;

1. `svn log` to get a list of revisions where the file is modified.
2. `grep` for lines with the revision number in it.
3. `sed` to strip out all the other info from the line, leaving just the revision numbers.
4. `xargs` (with -L 1) to repeatedly get the diff for the file from each specific revision, and finally...
5. `less` to make it "navigable"